# How do I run JavaScript in a console like environment?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to follow the the examples here

http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter2.html

and

```
print('blah');
```

Keeps trying to send to a physical printer when run in a browser.  I just want console output.

Comment: "print is not a standard JavaScript function, browsers do not provide it for you, but it is made available by this book, so you can use it on these pages"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want something simple, the Chrome console will let you run JavaScript on the fly.  To print text you can use `console.log('blah');`  And if you want to print multiple values, you can just list them all out as arguments (no need to concatenate) `console.log("a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3);`

You can bring it up with `control-shift i` then select the console tab on the far right.  And of course FireBug has a similar feature if you're more of a FireFox fan.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Almost all modern browsers have developer tools, which includes the a console. Look for developer tools in your browser, then look for the console.

Once you've found it, you can enter expressions manually, or place `console.log()` in the desired places in your code.

**Note:** Once you get used to the console, it will replace the need for the ever so annoying `alert(myVar)`.

**Additional Info**

Here's a decent overview/tutorial on using the console: https://web.archive.org/web/20150101222740/http://anemonesoft.com/os/cottage/doc/tutorial/console.html

Answer (score 1):

You can run javascript interactively from the command line. [This blog post](http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-on-the-command-line-or-as-a-shell-scripting-language) from ajaxian.com describes how to use the built-in javascript shells on Windows and Mac OS. When you're feeling especially lazy, you can also type commands into a browser-based javascript interpreter like [this one](http://www.squarefree.com/shell/shell.html).