# Creating JavaScript application for command line

Tags: javascript, command-line

Is is possible to create JavaScript application that runs on command Line or terminal **(NO CONSOLE)** without any browser or using any .html file. You can execute this file from command line.

I want to create a simple calculator that ask for first number, then second number and then operation.

**Demo how it should look in terminal (NOT CONSOLE) ?**

```
Enter 1st number: 10
Enter 2nd number : 30
Enter operation : +
Result : 40
```

If yes, any one please guide me through?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at Node.js or io.js: http://nodejs.org/, https://iojs.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cosider learn about nodejs:

http://nodejs.org/

And checkout express as its really easy and helps you setting out the initial configuration for a node app:

http://expressjs.com/

Also, check the accepted answer here:

[How do I run JavaScript in a console like environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994011/how-do-i-run-javascript-in-a-console-like-environment)

It talks about the chrome console.

Hope this resources help you out.

Comment: express is a framework create a web server. It doesn't seem like the OP wants to serve a website.

Comment: I didnt say that express is explicity for console, I just recommended as a lecture in order to have more resources to work with nodejs

Comment: Well, your statement makes it sounds like express is helpful to create any "node app", which is not the case. It's like you are trying to sell a car to a person and offer special rally tires (which the person will likely never need).

Comment: I'm not selling anything, just sharing resources.